# UnboundLocalError: local variable 'long' referenced before assignment

Tags: python-2.7

I'm trying to use `long` in a way that's compatible with both python 2 and 3, without using any external library (e.g. `six`).

Here's a minimal version of the code that reproduces the error `UnboundLocalError: local variable 'long' referenced before assignment`:

```
import sys

def f():
    if sys.version_info.major == 3:
        long = int
    print(long('42'))

f() # error
```

However, when I take the code outside the function, it prints out `42` properly:

```
import sys

if sys.version_info.major == 3:
    long = int
print(long('42'))
```

The error only occurs in python 2 (I'm using 2.7.11). I want to understand why this happens, and how to fix it gracefully without using external libraries.

Thanks!

Comment: `long` is in the global context. Add `global long` in the beginning of the function.

Comment: But python3 works just fine in `f()`. Is that a bug in python 2?

Comment: No, in python3 version long is a local variable and is not accessible outside of function scope, try using long outside of `f` function in python3 and it shouldn't work. You can do this setup in module scope.